# Dynamic string without realloc

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have this string malloced one byte:

```
char * word = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

I have another string `source.content`. The first few characters of this string needs to be copied to `word` and I use a loop to do the work:

```
for (int i = 0; isalnum(source.content[0]); ++i)
{
    word[i] = source.content[0];
    source.content += 1;
}
```

After the loop, I terminate `word`:

```
word[strlen(token.value)-1] = '\0';
```

My question is, why does the program above work when I copied more than 1 character to `word` even though it's only malloced for 1 character? When I realloaced an additional byte every loop, it does the same thing just slower.

Comment: it's undefined behavior to overflow a buffer. "undefined" doesn't mean _guaranteed_ to crash, it means what happens next is undeterministic as far as `c` is concerned

Comment: Is `token.value == word`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes sorry

Comment: Why would you make a 1 byte long char*, doesn't make any sort of sense.